# Base64 in Json: Is it a Good Idea for Rest API?

Tags: rest, json, file-handling

I am developing a Rest API, and I am asking myself:

Is it a good Idea to put base64 encoded data in Json, e.g. for file uploads? What if the base64 contains some of `{`,`}`,`:` characters and breaks the json content?

If is not a good idea, what alternatives are widely considered to be best practices?

Comment: How do you define "good idea?"  The JSON specification allows strings.  Base64 is string data; in fact, it's one way to get binary data into a string form so that you can put it into data containers that are text-based... like JSON.  Whether that arrangement adequately meets your needs is a different matter.

Comment: Try using a different content type other than json.  `application/octet-stream` may be one approach.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Base64 is a safe encoding for JSON.

The downside to using Base64 is that it's quite verbose. It can add significant overhead to your file upload which means longer upload and more bandwidth used. If it's possible I suggest using a binary protocol that supports JSON types. [CBOR](http://cbor.io/) is a popular one that ElasticSearch uses for document uploads. There is also [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/).

Comment: Base64 doesn't contain any of the characters the OP cited anyway.

Comment: I thought it didn't :)

Comment: @Robert Harvey:  Well... I remember one can define his own set of characters to be used for encoding in Base64. There may be a popular set that many people use but it is not certain that one Base64 implementation will use the same set as the next.